# How can I run a Python.exe on another computer that doesn't have Python installed?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have a Python.exe file that I created using Pyinstaller. It runs fine when I execute it on my own PC, but if I move it to another PC on the network, it gives the error pop up message "Fatal error detected, Failed to execute script __".

I am needing to run this Python exe on any computer on the network even if they don't have Python installed.

I used the code below and it packages everything into one single .exe file in the dist folder.

```
pyinstaller -F -w script.py
```

I am needing to run this Python.exe on any computer on the network even if they don't have Python installed. Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible. That is the whole purpose of `pyinstaller`. But it is clear that you are not bundling everything that your application needs into the .exe. Look at https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html to discover what the problem might be. This may be a longer process than you might like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out the solution to this problem.

I re-ran pyinstaller without -w and saw the error message in cmd "InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified."

My script used pyodbc and I was researching around and saw to change the driver to `"Driver={SQL Server}`;". I originally had it as `"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"`, so once I changed this to just SQL Server, the executable files ran fine on other machines.

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that `pyinstaller` is tailored to the specific OS it was created in (it is especially dependent on C implementation, app created by PyInstaller on, say, `ubuntu` with `glibc` will be incompatible with `alpine` running `musl`).
What's more, it is not standalone executable per se, it has Python interpreter bundled inside.

You can find some more info in [pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html).

Easiest workaround I have found is to use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and create your app with [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

If that's not an option, you may have to use Cython or other approach.